# Maximum count - PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, postgresql

I'm looking to pull the max(count(*)) of something from a table.

Effectively what i'm trying to do is pull out a customers favourite brand. So they buy 300 bars of soap a year but I'd like to know which their favourite is. So the max(count(brand_id) basically.

I was thinking of doing it like this:

```
    SELECT
 transaction.customer_id,
 max(occ) 
 FROM
 (  SELECT 
    transaction.customer_id,
    count(transaction.brand_id) as occ,
    FROM
    transaction

    GROUP BY
    transaction.customer_id,

) AS foo
GROUP BY
transaction.customer_id
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

you can do it like this:

```
with cte as (
    select customer_id, brand_id, count(*) as cnt
    from test1
    group by customer_id, brand_id
)
select distinct on (customer_id)
    customer_id, brand_id, cnt
from cte
order by customer_id, cnt desc
```

Keep in mind, that if there more than one brand with equal count for some customer, you'll end up with one arbitrary record. If you want to get all records, use dense_rank() function:

```
with cte1 as (
    select customer_id, brand_id, count(*) as cnt
    from test1
    group by customer_id, brand_id
), cte2 as (
    select
        customer_id, brand_id,
        dense_rank() over(partition by customer_id order by cnt desc) as rn
    from cte1
)
select customer_id, brand_id
from cte2
where rn = 1
```

**<kbd>[sql fiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!12/a0ca6/2)</kbd>**

For PostgreSQL 8.3:

```
select distinct on (customer_id)
    customer_id, brand_id, cnt
from (
    select customer_id, brand_id, count(*) as cnt
    from test1
    group by customer_id, brand_id  
) as c
order by customer_id, cnt desc;
```

**<kbd>[sql fiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!10/a0ca6/4)</kbd>**

Comment: @QuinnOlive yes, check the sql fiddle

Comment: My PostgreSQL is 8.3 unfortunately :/

Answer (score 0):

or `like this`

```
 with cte as (
    SELECT 
        transaction.customer_id,
        count(transaction.brand_id) as occ,
        FROM
        transaction

        GROUP BY
        transaction.customer_id
    )

    select max(occ) from cte
```

Comment: Will this work in PostgreSQL? I keep getting an error on the "AS"

Comment: @QuinnOlive: yes that should work with any supported version. CTEs where introduced with 8.4.

Comment: Ahhh. Bugger. My postgreSQL server is 8.3 :/